# Set size / thickness of a primitive type (point, line, etc.)

Tags: opengl, qt3d, pyside2

Is it in **Qt3D** possible to set a size or a thickness o a primitive type such as *Points*, *Lines*, *Triangles*, etc.?

```py
self.mesh = Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer()
self.mesh.setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender.QGeometryRenderer.LineStrip)
self.geometry = Qt3DRender.QGeometry(self.mesh)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class [QLineWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qlinewidth.html#smooth-prop) to set the width of rendered lines or [QPointSize](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qt3drender-qpointsize.html) to set the size of points. If you are looking to draw thicker lines on a wireframe model you can use the [wireframe example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3d-wireframe-example.html) as a basis.

If I understood your question wrong then maybe you can concertize it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! You have understood my question perfectly. I see `QLineWidth` and `QPointSize` useful however I do not understand how to set these two properties properly. I initialize these two classes but I how can I tell my `QEntity` to use these two properties?

Comment: Well, that's Qt3D's "sparse" documentation doing its work. They are both QRenderStates, which means you have to add them to a QRenderStateSet. The set has to be part of the framegraph.

Comment: OK, I added `Qt3DRender.QRenderStateSet().addRenderState(line_width)`.

Comment: I have a scene with a lines geometry and a points geometry. I add `QLineWidth` and `QPointSize` (as children of the same `QRenderStateSet`) to control the width of such primitives, but only `QPointSize` affects the size of points. Why `QLineWidth` does not work?

Comment: @fferri Please ask a new question, including a [minimally working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).